# Install log formatter in glassfish

Tags: jakarta-ee, glassfish, java.util.logging

I don´t like the output of the `com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter` which might be uniform but not very helpful. So in a first step I just replaced it with the `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter`. This actually works fine but for a `java.lang.ClassCastException` exception:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter cannot be cast to com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter

Being a perfectionist I want to get rid of this exception and I wonder if I can create my own child class from com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter and somehow install this class into glassfish.

How to install a custom log formatter into Glassfish?

Comment: Extending the logger from `java.util.logging.SimpleFormatter` is no longer a problem, but required (at least on GlassFish 3.1.2). See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609380/glassfish-3-how-do-you-change-the-default-logging-format for a complete example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look at [Configuring format of server log](http://www.java.net/node/706475) on the GlassFish forums. Basically, you need to:

- Implement your formatter
- Put the jar with your formatter in `domain_dir/lib/ext`.
- Declare it in `<mydomain>/config/logging.properties`

#### See also

- [Configuring Logging](http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4495/ghgwi?l=en&n=1&a=view)

Comment: I finally found time to create the needed loggers.  However they leave a little after-taste as I needed `auto-depends.jar` and `logging.jar` to compile and run as well as `common-util.jar` to run. All from `glassfish/modules`.That opens two rhetoric question: 1) How much memory did I just waste for a simple logger. 2) Who was the idiot who implemented `com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.UniformLogFormatter` as a class instead of an interface.