# Reducing line width of glassfish log

Tags: logging, glassfish, glassfish-3

Does anyone know how I can reduce the width of each line on a glassfish log. It seems to contain lots of information that I do not need. Below is an example of one line.

```
[#|2012-03-04T16:00:09.537+0000|INFO|oracle-glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-1;|16:00:09,537  INFO MyClassNameThatIsLogging:89 - LogMessageHere
```

All I really care about is:

- the time at the beginning - although not even in this much deatail (`2012-03-04T16:00:09.537+0000`)
- the log level (`INFO`)
- The classname/line number (`MyClassNameThatisLogging:89`)
- The message (`LogMessageHere`)

I dont care about this part

```
oracle-glassfish3.1|javax.enterprise.system.std.com.sun.enterprise.server.logging|_ThreadID=94;_ThreadName=Thread-1;
```

Where is this configured?

I have found [Install log formater in glassfish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3880452/install-log-formater-in-glassfish), but it seems a bit extreme. Do I really have to create my own logger?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A custom log handler seems to be the only option here.

The glassfish admin guide does describes the log format in detail:

```
[#|yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ss.SSS-Z|Log Level|ProductName-Version|LoggerName|Key Value Pairs|Message|#]
```

From: [Glassfish Admin Guide, Log Records](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/abluk.html#gkmex)

Further on it states:

> By default, Oracle GlassFish Server log records are captured in a server log file using the format described in Log Records. However, you may find that you want to log messages to a different location, such as a database or a remote server, or log messages from specific loggers to your own file. This can be done by implementing a custom log handler. This section explains how to add a custom log handler to the Oracle GlassFish Server logging service.

From: [Glassfish Admin Guide, Adding a Custom Logging Handler](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2416/gklmn.html#gklnk)

[This blog post](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/carlavmott/archive/2008/12/adding_custom_h.html) shows an example implementation.

Comment: Thanks TPete. I'll look at that. It does like a sledgehammer to crack a nut.